# Я создал словарь, но нужен вставить ключ, чтобы выбирать между англ и русс словарём.Как это сделать?

Tags: python

```
running = True
d = {"яблоко":"apple"}

while running:
    b = input("Введите слово:")
    if b in d:
        print(d[b])

    else:
        n = input("В словаре нет такого слова, введите перевод:")
        d.update({b:n})
        print(d)
    if b == "q":
        running = False
```

Comment: Непонятный заголовок, в вопросе просто какой-то кусок кода без пояснений. Почему помощь нужна Вам, а усилия, чтобы понять, чего Вы вообще хотите, должны прилагать другие?

Answer (score 1):

вам надо сделать перевод с русского на английский и с английского на русский?

**вариант 1:**

создайте 2 словаря и не мучайтесь `dict_en`, `dict_ru`

выбор между словарями можно делать такой:

1. если в слове присутствуют русские буквы - искать в русско-английском, если английские - искать в англо-русском
2. искать сразу в обоих словарях
3. в запросе указывать какой словарь нужен:

например так: "ru:нога" или "eng:leg" и на входе делать так:

```
lang, word = input("введите слово: ").split(':')
```

**вариант 2:**

вам нужен не словарь, а список, внутри которого будет кортеж `(ru, eng)`

по которому будет осуществляться поиск

Если вам нужна скорость выборки - тогда вариант 1, если вам нужно больше свободной памяти - вариант 2

P.S.

зачем вам вообще переменная `running`?

выходите из цикла по `break`

```
while True:
    b = input("Введите слово:")
    if b == "q":
        break
```

зачем лишние сущности плодить?

Comment: Ещё нужно продумать как переключать между словарями. Хотя можно и не переключать, а искать сразу в обоих версиях )

Comment: @CrazyElf или искать сразу в двух словарях или например так: "ru:нога" или "eng:leg" и на входе распарсивать

Comment: И опять же - если передавать одни и те же ссылки на слова в оба словаря, то лишний словарь будет по идее тратить будет память только на хэш и прочее сопустствующее, но не на сами слова